# Adding custom headers in the request to AWS load balancer

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-application-load-balancer

We need to setup multiple load balancers for different domains but they will all point to same EC2. In order to identify the domain(actually projectID) from which the request is coming, we need to add custom Headers in the request. For Eg
PROJECT-ID : test1

But currently I couldn't find a way to add custom headers in the request at Load balancer level.

Comment: You can't add headers at the load balancer level. Can't you just use the `Host` header?

Comment: This might help https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/elb-find-load-balancer-IP/

Comment: https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/custom-headers - Google cloud allows adding headers to request